# Cocoa saving text files when distributing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In the app I'm designing I have a couple text fields that each save to a .txt file when the app is closed, and then read back in when the app opens up; however, when I try to distribute the app (just exporting it as an application and dropboxing it to some friends) the people I'm sending it to don't have the file locations that I'm saving to on their computers, so the text fields don't save. Is there a way I can create the .txt files on their computers when the app downloads? or is there a better way to save when distributing than doing .txt files? Thanks.

Comment: Package Maker is a godsend in these kinds of situations.  As long as you're not averse to writing scripts, that is.

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use NSUserDefaults and store the (hopefully fairly small) text in the app's preferences database? It's guaranteed to exist and be accessible without running afoul of sandbox restrictions or nonstandard storage locations.

Beyond that, you'll need to provide more information if you want a direct answer to your question. Specifically, what is the exact path you're using and what is the exact error you're receiving? Why do you feel you need to bundle empty text files when all it takes is creating the file(s) at runtime?

Comment: I don't feel the need to bundle empty text files if I can create the files the first time it runs. How would you recommend I do this? Also, is it generally good practice to use NSUserDefaults to store save files for the program? What if they're bigger files, ie. custom objects?

Comment: Please provide the information I requested. You should be able to create the file at runtime; if you can't, post the *actual error* you encounter.

Comment: Did more research and figured out how to create files at runtime. That's what I was really asking, sorry for the confusion, I didn't really know what I was trying to do. There wasn't an error, I just had no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just package the initial .txt file in your application bundle. Check if the file exists on your user's local file system. If not, read your bundle's .txt file into a string, then save that string to the user's file system in the correct place.

```
NSError *fileError = nil;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    //Read the file
    NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&fileError];
    if (fileError) {
        //Handle the error
    }
} else {
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"initialFile" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *initialFileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&fileError];
    if (!fileError) {
        [initialFileContents writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&fileError];
        if (fileError) {
            //Handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your suggestion is I create the empty text files and bundle them with the application? How do I do this? Or would it be a better idea to just create the files at runtime as Joshua Nozzi suggested.

Comment: Completely unnecessary for empty files.

Comment: The only reason I suggested bundling them is because I thought the initial text file needed to have some text already in it. No, you should just create the file the first time you need to save text to it. I guess I really just don't understand your problem. When you call `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error`, if the file does not already exist at the specified location, it will create a file there, unless one or more of the directories in your path doesn't exist, at which point you should call `createDirectoryAtPath: withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` method of NSFileManager.